# how to add another console to interact with multi-threaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, console, pipe, gnu-screen

I have a single-threaded program doing some long-running computing job. The main thread is using the console for some output. I'm considering adding another thread to interact with user to query something like the job progress or process internal state.

Assuming synchronization is properly handled and the user interact with the second thread through something like a command line console (no GUI needed). What is a good way to implement this function? I guess I can make the second thread wait for commands at certain named pipe and let the user connect to this pipe using something like a GNU screen (I'm not sure whether it will work).

Are there any libraries (Java or non-Java) or tools to implement this? My program is running on Linux.

Comment: "My program is running on Linus." - While I know Java hasn't _completely_ lived up to the initial goal, this shouldn't matter.  All the libraries you actually need should be part of the standard set, especially for something like command-line interaction (although some 3rd party stuff may make it more tolerable).  Otherwise.... this question may be a little too broad, but this sort of thing often tries to parcel out the long-running job into pieces, so it can check for commands and update state.  Also, we recommend accepting some of the answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

Doing what you want would actually require two named pipes: one for each direction. Using a socket might be a better option in this regard (although it might be a bit harder to handle server-side).

As for the client, I don't think that GNU/Screen could be used to do this. If you use named pipes, the client should simply use `cat` (actually two `cat` processes: one to write to the server, one to read the answer). If you implement socket-based communications, you can use `netcat` (`nc`) for the client.

Answer (score 1):

You need another thread to read the input from the user. Here's how I would do it...

```
package com.mycompany.readthread;

import java.io.*;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Launcher().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        LongRunningJob job = new LongRunningJob();
        ReadInputLoop readInputLoop = new ReadInputLoop(job);
        Thread readInputLoopThread = new Thread(readInputLoop);
        readInputLoopThread.start();  // run read input loop in another thread
        job.run();  // run long running job in this thread
    }

    class LongRunningJob implements Runnable {
        private double percentageComplete;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // long running job
            // update percentageComplete in a synchronized block
        }

        public synchronized double getPercentageComplete() {
            return percentageComplete;
        }
    }

    class ReadInputLoop implements Runnable {
        private LongRunningJob job;               

        public ReadInputLoop(LongRunningJob job) {
            this.job = job;            
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                while (true) {
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if ("progress".equals(line)) {
                        double percentageComplete = job.getPercentageComplete();
                        System.out.println(String.format("%.3g", percentageComplete)+ "%");
                    }
                }                
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Unexpected exception");
            }
        }
    }
}
```