# How to interact with java application from command line to print runtime objects

Tags: java, object, oop, caching

Designing a alarm monitoring program in Linux with Java. My application listens couple of streams to receive alarms. It doesn't hold current alarms on the DB or any file.

What I want to do is after program is started I want to interact with application from command line then list existing active alarms with my own commands.

The Java Object Cache provides caching for Java objects. But how can i reach to cache from command line.

Example of what I'm looking for:

> java -jar AlarmReceiver.jar

> show active_alarms

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add another console to interact with multi-threaded program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653716/how-to-add-another-console-to-interact-with-multi-threaded-program)

Comment: Another answer might be: just use `new Scanner(System.in)`.  Unfortunately, your question is both very broad and very unclear.